# Xacml in tinyOS

Tags: rbac, xacml, tinyos, nesc

I have to implement an rbac in mica motes. I've read that Xacml helps in implementation of rbac. But I searched tutorials and google and I'm not able to find anything relevant.Can some one please explain how it should be done or any lead to references.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. TinyOS and nesC are about programming embedded systems in a low-level language. XACML is an XML based language/architecture dealing with expressing and enforcing access control policies. What's the relation?

Comment: Thanks, my question was how to enforce access control in these embedded systems.as i know there are  some interfaces in OSGI for XACML and i was not sure how do they enforce it in tinyos , for eg an implementation of smart grid

Comment: I meant implementation of communication among devices in smart grid.

Answer (score 0):

This blog would help you to know about xacml [1].  you can find the xacml samples that have been used rbac use cases from here [2] [3].  Actually in XACML, you can achieve both abac and rabc, it is based on how you define the xacml policy. in your policy, you can defined a "foo" resource can be read  by role "bar".  But actually you want to check the authorization for user "bob". Then there must be a PIP [4] where, it helps to find the roles of "bob".

[1] http://xacmlinfo.com/category/xacml/
[2] http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/08/16/xacml-sample-for-on-line-trading-application/
[3] http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/08/16/resource-filtering-with-xacml/
[4] http://xacmlinfo.com/2011/12/18/understanding-pip/

Comment: Hi thanks for your references.But dou you have any idea how do they implement it in tinyOS .As i dont have any experience in tinyOs before im not able to implement access control in NesC language